# BootstrapException while generate report using open office API

Tags: java, linux, openoffice.org

I have generate report using open office API, Report work fine in window but in Linux it will generate error like

```
 java.lang.Exception: com.sun.star.comp.helper.BootstrapException
2011-04-21 14:21:27,919 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at com.cc.crm.web.docpopulate.util.DocumentWriter.createDoc(DocumentWriter.java:82)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,919 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at com.cc.crm.web.docpopulate.util.DocumentWriter.populateTemplateData(DocumentWriter.java:526)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,919 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at com.cc.crm.web.reports.CRMReportServlet.getReportDataBytes(CRMReportServlet.java:111)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,919 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at com.cc.crm.web.reports.CRMReportServlet.doWebAction(CRMReportServlet.java:34)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,920 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at com.cc.crm.web.base.BaseWsServelt.doGet(BaseWsServelt.java:34)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,920 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,920 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,920 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,920 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,920 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,920 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,920 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,920 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,920 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,920 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,920 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,921 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,921 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,921 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,921 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,921 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,921 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,921 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,921 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,921 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,921 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,921 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,922 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2) Caused by: com.sun.star.comp.helper.BootstrapException
2011-04-21 14:21:27,922 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at ooo.connector.BootstrapConnector.connect(BootstrapConnector.java:129)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,922 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at ooo.connector.BootstrapSocketConnector.connect(BootstrapSocketConnector.java:68)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,922 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at ooo.connector.BootstrapSocketConnector.connect(BootstrapSocketConnector.java:45)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,922 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at com.cc.crm.web.docpopulate.util.DocumentWriter.createDoc(DocumentWriter.java:74)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,922 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   ... 26 more
2011-04-21 14:21:27,922 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2) java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (No such file or directory)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,923 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,923 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,923 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at com.cc.crm.web.docpopulate.util.Utility.getBytesFromFile(Utility.java:35)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,923 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at com.cc.crm.web.reports.CRMReportServlet.getReportDataBytes(CRMReportServlet.java:114)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,923 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at com.cc.crm.web.reports.CRMReportServlet.doWebAction(CRMReportServlet.java:34)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,923 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at com.cc.crm.web.base.BaseWsServelt.doGet(BaseWsServelt.java:34)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,923 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,924 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,924 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,924 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,924 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,924 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,924 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,924 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,924 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,924 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,924 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,924 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,924 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,925 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,925 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,925 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,925 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,925 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,925 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,925 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,925 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
2011-04-21 14:21:27,925 ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-20150-2)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Below i add OOo configuration code

if(context == null)
        {
            try
            {

```
            List oooOptions = OOoServer.getDefaultOOoOptions();
            oooOptions.add("-nofirststartwizard");
            OOoServer oooServer = new OOoServer(commonBundle.getString("OPEN_OFFICE_PATH"), oooOptions);

            // Connect to OOo
            BootstrapSocketConnector bootstrapSocketConnector = new BootstrapSocketConnector(oooServer);
            context = bootstrapSocketConnector.connect();


            //DocumentPopulateConfig
            //context = BootstrapSocketConnector.bootstrap(commonBundle.getString("OPEN_OFFICE_PATH"));
        }
        catch (BootstrapException e)
        {
            throw new java.lang.Exception(e);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Could it be a permission problem? You may provide some code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is it possible that its work in window and not in Linux ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is in the way Open Office is configured.  This exception appears to occur when connecting to your OOo server using connection parameters taken (I guess) from some config file.

Comment: Thank you your answer guide me lot